# How to know when two objects touch each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how would you know when two objects (such is divs and imgs) touch each other.  I am building a mario game and I want to be able to end the level when mario "rescues" (really just touches) princess peach.

Comment: By touches, do you mean that the tags are adjacent to eachother? `<div>divA</div><div>divB</div>` are touching?

Comment: You'd listen for the babies. When elements touch, all the babies in China cry.

Comment: But Chinese folks are only allowed to have two babies at max if and only if they were the only childs of their parents. What about that?

Comment: You have to calculate it in loop for each pair of active objects.

Comment: @Derija93 - doesn't matter, the princess isn't in China, and Mario will never find her anyway as he's not listening for the babies.

Comment: i recommend you http://gamequeryjs.com

Comment: or http://html5quintus.com/#demo

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you, you want to check when $('#mario').position() left / right / top is covering $('#peach') left / right / top.

Comment: do not forget the size of objects

Answer (score 0):

this will be perfect for you :

http://gamequeryjs.com/

anyway the thing you are looking for is called HitTest , try some google , but trust me this plugin i have attached above there will really help you alot.

and you know what , just in case you are almost done with your game and dont want to start over , use thsi directly http://plugins.jquery.com/e-smart-hittest-jquery/.