# How do I see if one element is touching another in JavaScript without clicking anything

Tags: javascript, html

OK so I've tried one thing from a different question and it worked, but not the way I wanted it to. it didn't work the way I wanted it to! You literally had to click when two objects were touching so it would alert you, if somebody can figure out a way to detect if two elements are touching without having to click that would be a life saver! So I hope you people who read this request please respond if you know how. this is the code below. so one object is moving  and i want it to make it stop when the object hits the player (i am making a game) the movement is by px.... i want it to keep testing if one object hits the player, and if it does i want it to stop everything.

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

boxes.forEach(function (el) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
      el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  } else {
      el.attachEvent('onclick', clickHandler);
  }
})

var detectOverlap = (function () {
    function getPositions(elem) {
        var pos = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        return [[pos.left, pos.right], [pos.top, pos.bottom]];
    }

    function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
        var r1, r2;
        if (p1[0] < p2[0]) {
          r1 = p1;
          r2 = p2;
        } else {
          r1 = p2;
          r2 = p1;
        }
        return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
    }

    return function (a, b) {
        var pos1 = getPositions(a),
            pos2 = getPositions(b);
        return comparePositions(pos1[0], pos2[0]) && comparePositions(pos1[1], pos2[1]);
    };
})();
function clickHandler(e) {

    var elem     = e.target,
        elems    = document.querySelectorAll('.box'),
        elemList = Array.prototype.slice.call(elems),
        within   = elemList.indexOf(elem),
        touching = [];
    if (within !== -1) {
        elemList.splice(within, 1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++) {
        if (detectOverlap(elem, elemList[i])) {
            touching.push(elemList[i].id);
        }
    }
    if (touching.length) {
        console.log(elem.id + ' touches ' + touching.join(' and ') + '.');
        alert(elem.id + ' touches ' + touching.join(' and ') + '.');
    } else {
        console.log(elem.id + ' touches nothing.');
        alert(elem.id + ' touches nothing.');
    }

}
```

this is my video game right now (please do not copy)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
/
<html>
  <form id="player" class="box">
  </form>
  <button type="button" class="up" onclick="moveup()">^</button>
  <button type="button" class="down" onclick="movedown()">v
  </button>
<style src="style.css">
    #player {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
position: relative;
bottom: -250px;
left: 200px;


}
 .up {
 position: relative; 
 bottom: -400px;
  




 }
 .down {
 position: relative; 
 bottom: -420px;
 



 }
 body {
 background-color: black;



 }
 #car {
 width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
position: relative;
bottom: -250px;
left: 600px;


 }
  </style>
  <form id="car" class="box"></form>
  <script>
  imgObj = document.getElementById('player');
imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
imgObj.style.bottom = '-250px'; 


function moveup() {
  imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
imgObj.style.bottom = '-250px'; 
  imgObj.style.bottom = parseInt(imgObj.style.bottom) + 70 + 'px';




}
function movedown() {
  imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
imgObj.style.bottom = '-250px'; 

 imgObj.style.bottom = parseInt(imgObj.style.bottom) + -120 + 'px';



}
myMove();
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("car");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 1000) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myMove();
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
  }
  }
  }
/* please do not copy; this is it so far i want the red box when it hits the player(blue box) to stop everything that is happening */
/* made by Jsscripter; car game */
  
 </script>
   </html>
```

Comment: I think what you are looking is an algorithm of collision detection, probably this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41557359/1360383

Comment: This might help you. Although there wasn't any straight answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254759/how-to-know-when-two-objects-touch-each-other

Comment: Looks like you just call `detectOverlap(element1, element2)` where `element1` and `element2` are set to the elements you want to check against.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vanilla JS Div Collision Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538882/vanilla-js-div-collision-detection)

Answer (score 0):

Intersection observer. API was largely developed because of news feeds and infinite scrolling. Goal was to solve when something comes into view, load content. Also is a great fit for a game.

> The Intersection Observer API lets code register a callback function
>   that is executed whenever an element they wish to monitor enters or
>   exits another element (or the viewport), or when the amount by which
>   the two intersect changes by a requested amount. This way, sites no
>   longer need to do anything on the main thread to watch for this kind
>   of element intersection, and the browser is free to optimize the
>   management of intersections as it sees fit.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

All major browsers except safari support the API. For backwards compatibility and Safari support can use the polyfill from W3C found [here](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill). Check out this example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Intersection_observer_concepts_and_usage):

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    //   entry.boundingClientRect
    //   entry.intersectionRatio
    //   entry.intersectionRect
    //   entry.isIntersecting
    //   entry.rootBounds
    //   entry.target
    //   entry.time
  });
};

var options = {
  root: document.querySelector('#scrollArea'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

var target = document.querySelector('#listItem');

observer.observe(target);
```

See this in action here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqpeMV